# Can not use spltOn to split String on spaces

Tags: haskell

I have a string containing words separated by spaces. I would like to get the individual words.

I verified (in ghci) that the following solution works well:

```
import Data.String
list_of_words = words "a b c"
```

but I happened to stumble accross [the splitOn function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.1.2.3/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:splitOn), and since I am still in the basement of Haskell programming, and a curious mind, I wondered whether I could also achieve my goal using this function. Hence I tried:

```
import Data.List
lw = Data.List.splitOn "a b c"
```

only to get the error message

> Not in scope: ‘Data.List.splitOn’
>
> No module named ‘Data.List’ is imported

I don't understand the first message, but the second one is ridiculous, since I imported the module, and the module name is shown in the ghci prompt. Then I realized that the website above referst to a module `Data.List.Split`, not `Data.List`. Hence I tried

```
import Data.List.Split
```

only to get the error messages

```
Could not find module ‘Data.List.Split’
```

Well, curiosity killed the cat. I should have stayed with my original `words` solution. But since I opened the box now, could some kind soul explain to me, why my attempts have failed, and how I could have it done correctly?

**UPDATE** Following the comments to my question, I tried

```
splitOn " " "a  c d"
```

but this time get the error message

> Variable not in scope: splitOn :: [Char] -> [Char] -> t
>
> Perhaps you meant one of these:
>
> ‘Text.splitOn’ (imported from Data.Text),
>     ‘splitAt’ (imported from Data.List),
>     ‘Text.splitAt’ (imported from Data.Text)

It looks like Data.Text (which I happened to import too) also has a `splitOn` function with different signature. Hence, I started a fresh ghci without any imports, and just did a

```
import Data.List
splitOn " " "a b c"
```

This gave also the error message

> Variable not in scope: splitOn :: [Char] -> [Char] -> t

Comment: The correct usage would be just `splitOn`, not `Data.List.splitOn`. You are confusing `import Data.List` with `import qualified Data.List`.

Comment: In addition to @AJFarmar's comment, your attempted usage of `splitOn` isn't quite correct either.  `splitOn :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]`, where the first list is the sublist to split the second argument on.  So for your example, the correct usage would be `splitOn " " "a b c"`.

Comment: @AJFarmar you can actually qualify identifiers in all cases. `qualified` only means you *must* do so.

Comment: @user4601931 The step you are missing is to install the *split* library with cabal and to make it available when starting ghci (`ghci -package split`, or something like that, I'm not sure).

Comment: @Li-yaoXia : I'm using _Stack_. Would the installation work with the _stack_ environment too?

Comment: I'm also surprised, that this question was voted to be closed, on the grounds that it is not a programming question. If this is not programming, what else would be? Or should I re-open it on, say, SO-Superuser?

Comment: Ah, yeah, the issue is that `Data.List` is a module in the `base` package, which doesn't export `splitOn`.  The module from `split` is `Data.List.Split`, so you need to install `split` and `import Data.List.Split (splitOn)`.  You can load the module in a GHCi session with `stack ghci --package split-0.1.2.3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the *split* library to be able to use it. Since you're a stack user here are the commands for that:

```
stack build split  # install split (some people prefer "stack build" over "stack install", but the difference concerns only executables)
stack ghci         # start ghci using the environment of packages installed by stack
```